# Return 0 if effective date > date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following:

```
df1['Effective_Date']
df1['Amount']

Date_Range = pd.date_range('12/31/2017', periods=150, freq='M')
```

I'm trying to return df2(rows = 'Amount', columns = Date_Range) where:

```
if df1['Effective_Date'] > Date_Range, return 0
```

E.g. Amount = $100 and Effective Date = 3/1/18, then it would return $0 on 2/28/18 and prior and $100 on 3/31/18, 4/30/18, 5/31/18, etc.

I was going to fill a dataframe with df1['Amount'] and then try to back out of amounts before the effective date:

To create dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1['Amount'], columns = Date_Range)
```

To make > effective date = 0:

```
df2[df1['Effective_Date'].astype(int) > df2] = 0
```

I get the following errors:

- Shape of passed values is (1, 1217), indices imply (150, 1217)
- cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]

I'm obviously an amateur. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can use [`less_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less_equal.html#numpy.less_equal) with [`ufunc.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) from numpy between the column 'Effective_Date' of `df1` and the `Date_Range`, that you multiply with the column 'Amount':

```
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame( np.less_equal.outer(df1.Efective_Date, Date_Range)
                                 *df1.Amount.values[:,None], 
                    columns = Date_Range)
```

with an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Efective_Date':pd.to_datetime(['01/26/2018', '04/22/2018', '03/28/2018']),
                    'Amount':[100,150,300]})
print(df1)

#   Amount Efective_Date
#0     100    2018-01-26
#1     150    2018-04-22
#2     300    2018-03-28

Date_Range = pd.date_range('01/31/2018', periods=6, freq='M')
print(Date_Range)

#DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30',
#               '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Then `df2` would be:

```
print (pd.DataFrame( np.less_equal.outer(df1.Efective_Date, Date_Range)
                                  *df1.Amount.values[:,None], 
                     columns = Date_Range))

#   2018-01-31  2018-02-28  2018-03-31  2018-04-30  2018-05-31  2018-06-30
#0         100         100         100         100         100         100
#1           0           0           0         150         150         150
#2           0           0         300         300         300         300
```